# C# reflection find property which type inherits some other type

Tags: c#, reflection

I'm wondering how to use the reflection mechanism in the following scenario:

```
public class A { }
public class B { }

public class ListA : ICollection<A> { }

public class ListB : ICollection<B> { }

public class Container
{
    public ListA LA { get; set; }
    public ListB LB { get; set; }
}
```

then I want to find a property, which type inherits the type `ICollection<B>`

```
var container = new Container();

var found = container.GetType().GetProperties().FirstOrDefault(x => x.PropertyType == typeof(ICollection<B>));
```

and of course the `found` variable is null, so how to move deeper with the reflection?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`List<B>` is of course not the same type as `ICollection<B>`. Thatswhy your `==` fails.

You need to check if the property type can be assigned to an `ICollection<B>`:

```
var found = typeof(Container).GetProperties()
              .FirstOrDefault(x => typeof(ITest<B>).IsAssignableFrom(x.PropertyType));
```

Alternatively you can check the interfaces that the `PropertyType` implements:

```
var found = typeof(Container).GetProperties()
              .FirstOrDefault(x => x.PropertyType.GetInterfaces().Contains(typeof(ICollection<B>)));
```

Comment: Do I correctly understand that first method should work with classes also?

Comment: @SamvelPetrosov yes.

Answer (score 1):

In case if you want to get class which implement some interface, in your case it's `ICollection<B>`, you can use the following code which use Reflection's `GetInterfaces()` method:

```
var container = new Container();

var found = container.GetType().GetProperties().FirstOrDefault(x => x.PropertyType.GetInterfaces().Contains(typeof(ICollection<B>)));
```